# PHP destroy session problems with back button of the browser

Tags: php

My problem is when I use the logout button, it does what is programmed, but when I use the back button of the browser it appears to me in the index as if it were a log-in.

Any suggestion

index.php

```
<?php
require 'header.php'
?>

<main>
    <?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['nombre']))require_once('Home.php');
    else echo '<p>Not login</p>';
    ?>

</main>
```

Home

```
<?php
$nombre=$_SESSION['nombre'];
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Logueado: <?php $nombre ?> </p>
</body>
</html>
```

logout

```
session_start();
session_unset();
session_destroy();
header('Location:../index.php');
```

Comment: it's just the page that is been cached... logout, then press the back button and then reload the page, and you will see that it will show you the "not logged" version

Comment: thanks, any way to clean cache

Comment: not the browser cache (if not reloading it), at least if you are not using some fancy js framework that does it for you, like angular vue or something like this, otherwise it's very difficult to do by yourself, due to browser and version compatibility (in other words, 90% of the websites have this problem, so don't be to afraid of this)... or oyu can set the page cache expire date as immediatly, but it's a very bad practice

Comment: if put this in home.php                                                                                                                `<?php
$nombre=$_SESSION['nombre'];
if(!isset($_SESSION['nombre']))
{ 
session_start();
session_unset();
session_destroy();
session_write_close();
setcookie(session_name(),'',0,'/');
session_regenerate_id(true);
$_SESSION['nombre'] = null;
header("Location: index.php");
die("Redirecting to: index.php"); 
} 
?>`

Comment: what's the question?

Answer (score -2):

you can also do that by adding this code :-

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    window.history.forward();
  </script>
```

it will prevent the user to get back from user dashboard Page to login Page.